# Is there a way to give prev() --or prevUntil()-- a numeric value?

Tags: jquery, css, list, menu, series

I want to apply the six previous and six next items of a list the same style as the current item, and a different style to the other items --those out of this -6/+6 range. (Pure css could do for six next, but i didn't manage to catch the 6 previous  ; + I want the class to be removed when an item is not within the range.)

So far, I have a functional yet redundant jquery piece of code. Is there a way to specify the prev() or prevUntil() function with a numeric value ? Something like prev(6) / next(6) ? Or should I use slice() ?

Here is the piece of code ($navigationLink/s refer to an anchor link in the page).

```
     if (!$navigationLink.parent().hasClass('sub-menu-current')) {
          $navigationLinks.parent().removeClass('sub-menu-current');
          $navigationLink.parent().addClass('sub-menu-current');
          $('li').removeClass('sub-menu-previous-1');
          $navigationLink.parent().prev().addClass('sub-menu-previous-1');
          $('li').removeClass('sub-menu-next-1');
          $navigationLink.parent().next().addClass('sub-menu-next-1'); 
          $('li').removeClass('sub-menu-previous-2');
          $navigationLink.parent().prev().prev().addClass('sub-menu-previous-2');
          $('li').removeClass('sub-menu-next-2');
          $navigationLink.parent().next().next().addClass('sub-menu-next-2');  
          $('li').removeClass('sub-menu-previous-3');
          $navigationLink.parent().prev().prev().prev().addClass('sub-menu-previous-3');
          $('li').removeClass('sub-menu-next-3');
          $navigationLink.parent().next().next().next().addClass('sub-menu-next-3');
          $('li').removeClass('sub-menu-previous-4');
   $navigationLink.parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().addClass('sub-menu-previous-4');
   $('li').removeClass('sub-menu-next-4');  
   $navigationLink.parent().next().next().next().next().addClass('sub-menu-next-4'); 
   $('li').removeClass('sub-menu-previous-5'); 
   $navigationLink.parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().addClass('sub-menu-previous-5');
   $('li').removeClass('sub-menu-next-5'); $navigationLink.parent().next().next().next().next().next().addClass('sub-menu-next-5');      
            $('li').removeClass('sub-menu-previous-6');
            $navigationLink.parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().addClass('sub-menu-previous-6');
            $('li').removeClass('sub-menu-next-6');
            $navigationLink.parent().next().next().next().next().next().next().addClass('sub-menu-next-6');                  
        }
```

NB : Ideally, the number of previous and next items to be displayed should match viewports, but that's probably too far from what I have here.

Comment: No - there's no option for `.prev(count)` as `.prev()` will only give the exact previous sibling.   Is there a reason you don't want to use a simple for loop?  (eg something like `var el = $(this);for (var i=0;i<6;++i) { el.addClass("sub-menu"); el = el.prev(); if (el==null) break; }` )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the code if you use the `prevAll/nextAll` function mixed with `slice`. In other words, you select all previous elements and the only take the first sixth.

After grouping, you can use `addClass` with a callback to add a class base on the index.

Here's an example:

```js
let $test_span = $( 'span' ).eq( 16 ).addClass( 'current' );

$test_span.parent().prevAll().slice( 0, 6 ).addClass( i => `previous-class-${i + 1}` );

$test_span.parent().nextAll().slice( 0, 6 ).addClass( i => `next-class-${i + 1}` );
```

```css
.current{ color:green; }
[class^="previous"]{ color : red }
[class^="next"]{ color : blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>1</span></div>
<div><span>2</span></div>
<div><span>3</span></div>
<div><span>4</span></div>
<div><span>5</span></div>
<div><span>6</span></div>
<div><span>7</span></div>
<div><span>8</span></div>
<div><span>9</span></div>
<div><span>10</span></div>
<div><span>11</span></div>
<div><span>12</span></div>
<div><span>13</span></div>
<div><span>14</span></div>
<div><span>15</span></div>
<div><span>16</span></div>
<div><span>17</span></div>
<div><span>18</span></div>
<div><span>19</span></div>
<div><span>20</span></div>
<div><span>21</span></div>
<div><span>22</span></div>
<div><span>23</span></div>
<div><span>24</span></div>
<div><span>25</span></div>
<div><span>26</span></div>
<div><span>27</span></div>
<div><span>28</span></div>
<div><span>29</span></div>
<div><span>30</span></div>
<div><span>31</span></div>
<div><span>32</span></div>
<div><span>33</span></div>
<div><span>34</span></div>
<div><span>35</span></div>
<div><span>36</span></div>
<div><span>37</span></div>
<div><span>38</span></div>
<div><span>39</span></div>
<div><span>40</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's index function](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the index of your current item relative to its siblings; use that value to select the others using [jQuery's eq function](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), some like this:

```
for(var i = -6;i < 7; i++)
    if(i !== 0)
        $('input').eq($('#cur').index() + i).css('color', 'red');
```

Needs refactoring but I hope puts on the right track